# Remove keys from Zapier Storage older than 1 month old

Tags: zapier

I need help create a Zap that remove Keys from a Zapier Storage older than 1 month old, I'm not using Python Store Client (i know those are removed after 3 months of last use) but I'm using Zapier Storage, any idea in how to achieve this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

First things first - both the `Storage by Zapier` app and the Python / JS store clients all use the same backend. Ergo, keys that haven't been touched in 3 months are purged, regardless of which client originally added them. If that knowledge fixes your problem, great!

If the 1 month window is important, there are a few options.

1. whenever you write the key, add another step on a 1 month delay that removes it
2. store the info with the date it was written. Then periodically (weekly?) get all the values, iterate over them to find the values that are outside your window, and delete those.

Those are the best ways I can think to do it. Hope that points you in the right direction!